# leader election process on uppaal

Tags: oop, leader, uppaal

I have such a connection in my topology:

https://courses.cs.ttu.ee/w/images/e/e5/ITI0130_Lab3_IEEE1394.pdf

I have written such a declaration to run a simulation on uppaal:

```
const int N=7;
const int d1=1;
const int d2=2;
const int d3=3; 
typedef int[0,N] id_t;
id_t Id;
const bool nb[N+1][N+1]=
{
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0},
{0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0},
{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0}
};

urgent chan req[N+1];
urgent chan ack[N+1];
id_t req_[N+1], ack_[N+1];
```

The array specifies the connection of nodes with indexes. For instance, node "0" is not connected with any node, so it has 0 in all the indexes. But node "1" is connected with node "2, 4, 5". So it has 1 in that indexes.

Now I get two leaders when I run the simulation.

I have to connect node "0" to the topology to get one leader when I run the simulation.

I have tried to connect node "0" to some nodes, but it hasn't worked.

This is my model:

[image]

How can I manage to do this?

Comment: I very much doubt you have written this program in 3 different programming languages, so please pick on and remove the other tags.

Comment: Normally, I had to find "uppaal" tag, but because of I couldn't, I have put some tags which may attract beneficial people's interest :)

Comment: You have enough reputations, if you put "uppaal" tag, I would so appreciate it.

Comment: Done. I have no idea what this tool does though, so if you could add some text to the new [uppaal tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uppaal) that would be great (as in how and when the tag should be used, rather than some copy/paste from wikipedia).

Comment: I have some problem while simulation. Can you show the node declaration? I also think that to make node 0 leader you need to change your matrix.(the first raw)